# How do I correctly call a templated superclass' constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a relatively basic Base class and Derived class, and getting stumped by an error I don't know how to resolve.

The code I've written is this:

```
template<bool Owning>
class Base {
protected:
    Base() = default;

    Base(int * ptr) {
        //Do something
    }
};

template<bool Owning>
class Derived : public Base<Owning> {
public:
    Derived() : Base(new int(5)) 
    {}
};
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
<source>: In constructor 'Derived<Owning>::Derived()':
<source>:14:17: error: class 'Derived<Owning>' does not have any field named 'Base'
   14 |     Derived() : Base(new int(5))
      |                 ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Clearly, there's something wrong with how I'm trying to call the Base class' constructor, but I don't know what the correct way to write this is. What should I be writing to get this code to behave properly?

Comment: `Base<Owning>(new int(5))`

Comment: OT: Why are you creating a pointer to a single `int` value? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's called creating a [mcve]: I just needed to reduce the problem down to a version that showed the error I was facing. The actual code I'm working on is very different to this, but reliably produces the same error.

Comment: @john If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You could have made it [even simpler](https://godbolt.org/z/913dYs) ;)